# S3 and order of classes

Tags: r, glmnet

I've alway had trouble understanding the the documentation on how S3 methods are called, and this time it's biting me back.

I'll apologize up front for asking more than one question, but they are all closely related. Deep in the heart of a complex set of functions, I create a lot of `glmnet` fits, in particular logistic ones. Now, `glmnet` documentation specifies its return value to have both classes "glmnet" and (for logistic regression) "lognet". In fact, these are specified in this order.

However, looking at the end of the implementation of `glmnet`, righter after the call to (the internal function) `lognet`, that sets the class of `fit` to "lognet", I see this line of code just before the return (of the variable `fit`):

```
class(fit) = c(class(fit), "glmnet")
```

From this, I would conclude that the order of the classes is in fact "lognet", "glmnet".

Unfortunately, the fit I had, had (like the doc suggests):

```
> class(myfit)
[1] "glmnet" "lognet"
```

The problem with this is the way S3 methods are dispatched for it, in particular `predict`. Here's the code for `predict.lognet`:

```
function (object, newx, s = NULL, type = c("link", "response", 
    "coefficients", "class", "nonzero"), exact = FALSE, offset, 
    ...) 
{
    type = match.arg(type)
    nfit = NextMethod("predict") #<- supposed to call predict.glmnet, I think
    switch(type, response = {
        pp = exp(-nfit)
        1/(1 + pp)
    }, class = ifelse(nfit > 0, 2, 1), nfit)
}
```

I've added a comment to explain my reasoning. Now when I call predict on this `myfit` with a new datamatrix `mydata` and `type="response"`, like this:

```
predict(myfit, newx=mydata, type="response")
```

, I do not, as per the documentation, get the predicted probabilities, but the linear combinations, which is exactly the result of calling `predict.glmnet` immediately.

I've tried reversing the order of the classes, like so:

```
orgclass<-class(myfit)
class(myfit)<-rev(orgclass)
```

And then doing the predict call again: lo and behold: it works! I *do* get the probabilities.

So, here come some questions:

1. Am I right in 'having learned' that
   S3 methods are dispatched in order
   of appearance of the classes?
2. Am I right in assuming the code in
   `glmnet`would cause the wrong order
   for correct dispatching of
   `predict`?
3. In my code there is nothing that
   manipulates classes
   explicitly/visibly to my knowledge.
   What could cause the order to
   change?

For completeness' sake: here's some sample code to play around with (as I'm doing myself now):

```
library(glmnet)
y<-factor(sample(2, 100, replace=TRUE))
xs<-matrix(runif(100), ncol=1)
colnames(xs)<-"x"
myfit<-glmnet(xs, y, family="binomial")
mydata<-matrix(runif(10), ncol=1)
colnames(mydata)<-"x"
class(myfit)
predict(myfit, newx=mydata, type="response")
class(myfit)<-rev(class(myfit))
class(myfit)
predict(myfit, newx=mydata, type="response")
class(myfit)<-rev(class(myfit))#set it back
class(myfit)
```

Depending on the data generated, the difference is more or less obvious (in my true dataset I noticed negative values in the so called probabilities, which is how I picked up the problem), but you should indeed see a difference.

Thanks for any input.

**Edit**:

I just found out the horrible truth: either order worked in glmnet 1.5.2 (which is present on the server where I ran the actual code, resulting in the fit with the class order reversed), but the code from 1.6 requires the order to be "lognet", "glmnet". I have yet to check what happens in 1.7.

Thanks to @Aaron for reminding me of the basics of informatics (besides 'if all else fails, restart': 'check your versions'). I had mistakenly assumed that a package by the gods of statistical learning would be protected from this type of error), and to @Gavin for confirming my reconstruction of how S3 works.

Comment: When I run your code I get the order `"lognet" "glmnet"` after the first `class` call, which is backwards from what you say you got.  I have glmnet 1.7; what version do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the order of dispatch is in the order in which the classes are listed in the class attribute. In the simple, every-day case, yes, the first stated class is the one chosen first by method dispatch, and only if it fails to find a method for that class (or `NextMethod` is called) will it move on to the second class, or failing that search for a `default` method.

No, I do not think you are right that the order of the classes is wrong in the code. The documentation appears wrong. The intent is clearly to call `predict.lognet()` first, use the workhorse `predict.glmnet()` to do the basic computations for all types of lasso/elastic net models fitted by **glmnet**, and finally do some post processing of those general predictions. That `predict.glmnet()` is **not** exported from the **glmnet** NAMESPACE whilst the other methods are is perhaps telling, also.

I'm not sure why you think the output from this:

```
predict(myfit, newx=mydata, type="response")
```

is wrong? I get a matrix of 10 rows and 21 columns, with the columns relating to the intercept-only model prediction plus predictions at 20 values of lambda at which model coefficients along the lasso/elastic net path have been computed. These do not seem to be linear combinations and are one the response scale as you requested.

The order of the classes is not changing. I think you are misunderstanding how the code is supposed to work. There is a bug in the documentation, as the ordering is stated wrong there. But the code is working as I think it should.

Comment: Great answer, but one small niggle: you can't alter the class during method dispatch: https://gist.github.com/1043952 (well you can, it just doesn't affect dispatch)

Comment: Also, it does seem that the intent is `predict.lognet` then `predict.glmnet`.  But as I read it, the OP says it's running `predict.glmnet` first on his system because the order of the classes is reversed.

Comment: @hadley thanks for pointing that out. I must have misremembered that. Fixed now.

Comment: @Aaron I got the impression that @Nick Sabbe was purposely reversing the class order of the object to show what he thought the correct ordering should be. Running this on my system I get the correct order up to and including the first `predict()` call. Let's see what @Nick has to say.

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for the input. See my edit. I'll accept @Gavin's response, since it does answer the concrete questions I asked.